# How to use parameters

Tags: php, symfony

lets say i have this URL:

```
/people/1/friends
```

Both People and Friend are objects, one Person can have many Friends

FriendController looks like this

```
class FriendController extends Controller
{
  public function indexAction()
  {
      $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

      $entities = $em->getRepository('EpiForumBundle:Friend')->findAll();

      return $this->render('EpiForumBundle:Friend:index.html.twig', array(
          'entities' => $entities,
      ));
  }

}
```

This index action works well but as you can see it returns every Friend in the database. I would like to get just friends with 'people_id' == 1. How can I select wanted friends? in other words, how can i get parameter which tells us about specific person?

UPDATE

Routes

```
friend:
    pattern:  /
    defaults: { _controller: "EpiForumBundle:Friend:index" }
```

Comment: I think using ParamConverter might be just confusing things at this point in your development.  You need to understand how to build queries with query builder: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#querying-for-objects-using-doctrine-s-query-builder

Comment: @Cerad Yeah, I think you are right. When he posted his URL, I assumed that he had the basics of routing down. I guess not.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using [ParamConverters](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html):

```
/**
 * @Route("/people/{id}/friends")
 * @ParamConverter("person", class="EpiForumBundle:Person")
 * @Template
 */
public function indexAction(Person $person)
{
    return array(
        'friends' => $person->getFriends()
    );
}
```

Comment: i get exception "Class Epi\ForumBundle\Controller\Section does not exist" (in my app i use Section and Category instead of People and Friends, i changed it here to make it more readable)

Comment: @Leo, sounds like you forgot a `use` statement for `Epi\ForumBundle\Entity\Section` or similar.

Comment: yes, i did forget about that, but now i get "Unable to guess how to get a Doctrine instance from the request information."

Comment: @Leo what does your route look like. Are you using annotations?

Comment: @Leo, there's your problem. Your route doesn't contain any placeholders. E.g.: {id}
Maybe you can try annotations for routing. I find it better to have configuration next to the controllers. [Look here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html#activation)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59476/discussion-between-leo-and-keyboardsmasher).

Comment: so how exactly should i improve this route?

Comment: @keyboardSmasher By returning an array this answer implies the use of the template annotation which was not added to your method.

Comment: @BraydenWilliams Good catch. :) `indexAction` probably isn't a good function name for route: `/people/{id}/friends` either. lol

Answer (score 0):

Your route should look like:

```
friend:
    pattern:  /people/{id}/friends
    defaults: { _controller: "EpiForumBundle:Person:friends" }
```

Then you should have a controller method like:

```
class PersonController
{
    public function friendsAction($id)
    {
        $friends = $this->getRepository('EpiForumBundle:Friend')->findBy(array(
            'person' => $id
        ));

        return $this->render('EpiForumBundle:Person:friends.html.twig', array(
            'friends' => $friends,
        ));
    }
}
```

Note that my route differs slightly than yours. I have made my route call the `friendsAction` inside a `PersonController`. I also used a more descriptive name to describe the entities that I am passing to my template.

If you want to step it up a notch, use a ParamConverter annotation, and you can type hint the Person object and the ID will be converted behind the scenes. You'll probably want to pass the Person to the template.

```
class PersonController
{
    /**
     * @ParamConverter("person", class="EpiForumBundle:Person")
     */
    public function friendsAction(Person $person)
    {
        $friends = $this->getRepository('EpiForumBundle:Friend')->findBy(array(
            'person' => $person
        ));

        return $this->render('EpiForumBundle:Person:friends.html.twig', array(
            'person'  => $person,
            'friends' => $friends,
        ));
    }
}
```

Also, as other answers have shown, using annotations for your routes is far more intuitive than using Yaml. So once you understand how this all works, go ahead and read:  http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html

Comment: i come from Rails so i dont really know, but isn't it bad practice not to have different actions and controllers for each model?

Comment: unfortunately this keeps telling me that i need to provide value for $id even though i put your route in both person person.yml and friend.yml

Comment: You only need to define the route once.  Could you add the entirety of your routing file and your controller to http://gist.github.com or add them to your original question?  Also, provide the output of  `app/console router:match /people/1/friends`.